LED selectable lights changing color when first turned on
I installed retrofit recessed HALO RA 5/6 Integrated LED selectable lights in two separate rooms and in both rooms when I turn turn on the lights, the lights first turn on as the warmest color (2700k) and then it changes to my selected color (3000k). It's about a half second change, but noticeable. Is it a defect with the lights itself or is there something wrong with my electrical wiring? These rooms were both an addition during a remodel so I'm wondering if the electricians didn't do a good job with wiring things together.

Wiring provides power. It doesn't control a device's configuration. This sounds like a product support issue.

Are they on a standard toggle switch or a dimmer?

they are on a standard toggle switch

This is absolutely not an issue with your wiring.
Look at the info that came with the lights. It may tell you that an operating feature is as you described. ( color change to your selection)
If you do not have the info, contact the manufacturer and describe the issue. They will either confirm that it is a common feature or a problem and you can make a warranty claim.

I looked at both spec page and installation manual - no mention of this. But I'd be willing to bet the microcontroller is doing a self-test cycle through everything before settling on the selected settings.

so if it's doing a self-test, does that mean there's nothing I can do about it?

@Anh, maybe, maybe not. This is why you contact the manufacturer.

I don't see mention of the phenomenon in reviews of what I assume is your product. You'd do well to add a product link to your question and update with switch info. Don't leave us to guess.
